# Segmentation fault (core dumped) c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coredump

My code is posted below, i'm pretty sure that the segmentation fault is happening in the while loop at the bottom of main().

My program has to read a file, the data is in a grid formation, the fscanf gets teh dimensions of the grid, then creates a 2D array with those dimensions, then i use a while loop to go through line by line and then a for loop to go through character by character in that line to store it in the inner part of the array, then i++ goes to store it in the next level of the 2D array.

can anyone tell me why its doing it?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    char direction;
    int steps;
    int cur[2];
    char** gridArray;
    int* move(int cur[2]);
    int* getCommand(int next[2], char** gridArray);
    char** make2DFileArray(int sizeX, int sizeY);
    int* makeArray(int size);

    int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
    {
            FILE *fp;
            int rows;
            int columns;
            int i=0,j;
            char line[1000];

            if ((argc < 2)^(argc > 3)) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: thebox mapfile [maxsteps]\n");
                    exit(1);
            }
            if( argc < 3 ) { steps = 10; }
            else { steps = argv[2]; }

            fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
            if( fp == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Missing map file.\n");
                    exit(1);
            }

            fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &rows, &columns);
            gridArray = make2DFileArray(rows+1, columns);

            while ( fgets(line, 1000, fp) != NULL) {
                for(j=0; j < columns - 1; j++) {
                        gridArray[i][j] = line [j];
                }
                i++;
                printf("%s", line);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        printf("(sidepos)>\n");
        return 0;
}
```

and my helper method, is this

```
char** make2DFileArray(int sizeX, int sizeY)
{
        int i;
        char** array;
        array = (char**) malloc(sizeX*sizeof(char*));

        for (i = 0; i < sizeX; i++) {
                array[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeY*sizeof(char));
                return array;
        }
        return array;
}

int* makeArray(int size)
{
        int* array;
        array = (int*) malloc(size*sizeof(int));
        return array;
}
```

Comment: Did you really mean to write this `if ((argc < 2)^(argc > 3))` ?

Comment: What is the inner `return array;` for in  `make2DFileArray()`? Is it a typo?

Comment: A good start would be to run your program in a debugger. The debugger will then stop when and where the crash happens. You can then examine the function call stack, and walk up it if the crash doesn't happen in your own code. The debugger will also let you examine the values of variables to help you understand why the crash might have happened.

Comment: If you still can't figure it out, then at least run the program in a debugger, and get a listing of the function call stack that you can attach to your question. It will help us help you quicker.

Comment: i don't think i can run it through a debugger,its 
for university and i'm running it through Putty.
yeah if argc is less than 2 it asks for more arguments, and more than 3 arguments is invalid as well.
Ah the return array thing in make2DFileArray kept giving me warnings until i put that in

Comment: To get more out of the build process just compile with more warnings on. For gcc using the options `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` help a lot. When having compiled using the option `-g` a command like `gbd /<somepath>/myexecutable` starts up the debugger. Then issueing the debugger command `run` followed by pressing the enter key brings you to the code line which crashed your app. A `backtrace full` then shows you where you are and what the surroundings variables carry. Enlightening ... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in the `make2DFileArray` function. You just return after the first allocation in the loop, meaning only `gridArray[0]` will be allocated.

Since none of the other entries will be allocated, accessing e.g. `gridArray[1]` is undefined behavior and the cause of your crash.

Comment: so i should just remove the first return array?

Comment: @AaronTroeger Yes you should, the one *inside* the loop should not be there.

Comment: Yes its working! thank-you so much :) i always seem to miss these silly little errors

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeX; i++) {
  array[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeY*sizeof(char));
  return array;
}

return array;
```

... should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeX; i++) {
  array[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeY*sizeof(char));
}

return array;
```

... in your function `make2DFileArray`.

**Remark:** The element is allocated memory however the rest of the elements are not because of your `return` inside the for-loop. Each element in the array from [1 ... length - 1] are random memory addresses (because when you `malloc` you did not populate them as proper pointers) and hence dereferencing any element other than the one at position 0 will result in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

```
steps = argv[2];
```

The variable 'steps' type is `int`, and variable 'argv[2]' type is `char *`, can't be directly assigned.

You can do it by

```
steps = atoi(argv[2]);
```

Comment: In this case `atoi()` is unsave, as it returns `0` in case of not being able to convert its argument (here: `arg[2]`) to an `int`.  A safe approach is using `strtol()` to convert a "string" to an integer.